# Javascript replaceChild

Tags: javascript, html, replace

I have a line of html that I need to change dynamically based on screen size.  I have the javascript that will check the screen size but I am having trouble getting it to replace the html with what I need.  I need to remove the link tag and only have the text and divs for styling.  The first line of code is what I have, the second is what I need it to change to:

```js
var smsLink = document.getElementById("smsTextLink");
var smsTextNode = document.createTextNode('text us agents available 8am - 10pm CST 7 Days a Week');
smsTextLink.parentNode.replaceChild(smsTextNode, smsTextLink);
```

```html
<a href="" id="smsTextLink">text us
  <div style="color:#888888">agents available 8am - 10pm CST<br>7 Days a Week</div>
</a>
text us
<div style="color:#888888">agents available 8am - 10pm CST<br>7 Days a Week</div>
```

Comment: you want to modify just the textContent?

Comment: Why not show/hide the divs?

Comment: I need to have only the text, but I am having trouble getting the styling to work, I guess I would need to combine textNodes and div nodes to create one node that I could use to replace it with

Comment: basically, on a large screen, it should not be a link and on a small screen I need it to be a link.

Comment: I could not understand your question 100%, but from what I got you could either edit the text `element.textContent` or hide the nodes you don't want `element.style.display = "none"` or manage their classes `element.className = "hidden"`

Comment: someone posted an answer stating I could use: smsTextLink.outerHTML = smsTextLink.innerHTML; but it was taken down for some reason, can someone elaborate as why this might be good/bad?

Answer (score 0):

you are referencing

```
var smsLink = document.getElementById("smsLink");
```

but in your html it is `id="smsTextLink"`

Comment: sorry, copied wrong line of code, I have updated to the correct line

Comment: someone posted an answer stating I could use:  smsTextLink.outerHTML = smsTextLink.innerHTML;